# Adding/cloning a section of form repeatedly in a modal popup

Tags: forms, design-patterns, modal-windows, bootstrap

Here is the scenario:
There is a modal popup in which each step has a certain form fields. on the last step, I need to repeat a section (last 3 fields) on a form repeatedly.

Here is what I thought:
have a add and delete button at the end of a section, to clone the section and append it to the previous one and since it is a modal, have a scrollbar for the entire section.

Is there a better way to do this?
Plz share how would you do this?

Current issues: Adding the scroll is making the modal messy.

Thanks[image: screenshot of the design]

Comment: If possible try to add heading for each section to distinguish each other.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to display more fields vertically in order to avoid overflow, my suggestion would be to use Tabs:

[image]

Either on the bottom as the group of fields is the last one, or on the right side.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Its a good idea, Incase the Manufacturer section reaches up to 12-15,  how to make this work is what I am thinking. Any thoughts?

Comment: 12-15 sounds like too many tabs for a modal view without any overflow. You could also use some kind of horizontal slides, similarly to the tabs, and simply use numbers as buttons:  #1  #2  #3  +
Just make sure the user understands the "buttons" belong to the box, and not to the whole modal.

Comment: Hiding the sections under tab is not a right solution. It can be wide open like your screenshot.